# Decide the third corner in equilateral triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have problem from an old exam below:

> An equilateral triangle $ABC$ lies in plane $x − y + 2z = 0$. The triangle has a corner in the origin (i.e., $A$ = origin), one to the corner in the point $B = (1,1,0)$, and its third corner has a positive x-component. Determine triangle third corner $C$.

I know that the plane's vector is $(1,-1,2)$ and it is perpendicular to the plane.
And you could think out another vector that is from the point $B$ like.
$(1,1,0) - (0,0,0) = (1,1,0)$ if you subtract that from the origin but after that I get stuck on how to decide the third corner in this problem how should I continue to solve this problem?

Comment: To start: *equilateral* tells you that all the side lengths must be the same, so the distances between $C$ and $B$ and between $C$ and $A$ must both be equal to the distance between $B$ and $A$, which is $\Vert(1,1,0)-(0,0,0)\Vert$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit normal vector is $\vec{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\langle 1,-1,2\rangle$ and the vector $\overrightarrow{AB}=\langle 1,1,0\rangle$.

Using Rodrigue's rotation formula, the rotation of $\overrightarrow{AB}$ about $\vec{n}$ by $\pm 60^\circ$ is
$$\overrightarrow{AC}=\frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow{AB}\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\vec{n}\times\overrightarrow{AB}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{n}(\vec{n}\cdot \overrightarrow{AB})$$
Since we have
$$\vec{n}\times\overrightarrow{AB}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\langle -2,2,2\rangle$$
$$\vec{n}\cdot\overrightarrow{AB}=0$$
Our equation for $\overrightarrow{AC}$ simplifies to
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{AC}
&=\frac{1}{2}\langle 1,1,0\rangle\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\langle -1,1,1\rangle\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\langle 1,1,0\rangle -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\langle -1,1,1\rangle\\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}\left\langle 1+\sqrt{2},1-\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}\right\rangle}
\end{align}

Comment: One question what does Rodrigo's Rotation formula calculate? Is the points after you rotated the triange?

Comment: @john It calculates the vector, which can easily be translated to a point.

Answer (score 1):

Since triangle is equilateral the third corner is the intersection of two circle with radius $R$ one centered at $O(0, 0, 0)$ another on point $A(1,1,0)$. Theses circles are the intersections of two spheres on theses centers with plane $x-y+2z=0$. So first we find $R$:

$$R=OB=\sqrt{1^2+1^2+0^2}=\sqrt 2$$

and establish following system of equations:

$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2=2\\ x-y+2z=0\end{cases}$

which gives the equation of circle on O.

$\begin{cases}(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=R^2=2\\ x-y+2z=0\end{cases}$

which gives the equation of circle on A.

Could you continue?